# I'm trying to make a poll command for my discord bot, but it keeps giving me the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The title pretty much says it all, I'm wondering if anyone could help me.
I'm using discord v11.5.1

Here is my code:

```
exports.run = async (bot, message) => {
    const options = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    const regex = /(["'])((?:\\\1|\1\1|(?!\1).)*)\1/g;
    const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
    let question, choices, content = [];
    let match;

    message.delete();
    for(let i=1;i<args.length;i++) {
        if(args[i].startsWith('"')) break;
        else question.push(args[i]);
    };

    question = question.join(" ");

    while(match = regex.exec(args.join(" "))) choices.push(match[2]);
    for(let i=0;i<choices.length;i++) content.push(`${options[i]} ${choices[i]}`);
    content = content.join("\n");

    message.channel.send(`${message.author} **started a poll**`, new(require("discord.js")).RichEmbed().setColor(0xbc13fe).setTitle(`:bar_chart: **Poll |** ${question}`).setDescription(content).setTimestamp()).then(async m => {for(let i=0;i<choices.length;i++) await m.react(options[i])});
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `let question, choices, content = []` you create three variables. `content` will be an empty array, `question` and `choices` will be `undefined`.

If you want to initialise them all with empty arrays, you can do it like this:

```js
let question = [];
let choices = [];
let content = [];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the solution that ended up working for me, have a great weekend! :)

Answer (score 0):

if below are all array, then you want to initialize it with empty array, then use `=` instead of comma `,`

```
 let question = choices = content = [];
```

instead of

```
 let question, choices, content = [];
```

Comment: I won't downvote this, but I don't think it's a good solution. Although `choices` and `question` will be initialised with an empty array, they will be no longer block scoped and become available on the global object, outside the `run()` method. Your solution is the same as `global.content = []; global.choices = []; let question = [];`.